# Timing in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, time

Hello So I am making a simple timed addition program for the little kids in my school. How do I make it so that after 5 seconds it will do:

```
print ("Try again")
```

here is my code

```
running = True  
import time
from random import randint

while running:
  print ("Hello world!")
  time.sleep(1.5)
  print ("Thank you for running this program, if not I would have been     trapped here for like EVER!")
  time.sleep(2.5)
  print ("My name is ιllιlııllııllııllıιllιlı.")
  time.sleep(2.5)
  print ("Crap! It seems like my system is still bugged I cant diplay my name")
  time.sleep(2.5)
  print ("You are going to have to help me")
  time.sleep(2.5)
  print (5000 * '-')
  time.sleep(2.5)
  print ("Here is how you are going to have to help me, I need you to solve math problems in order to get me out of here, I am going to give you 5 seconds to solve them!")
  time.sleep(10)
  print ("Ok this is going to start in 3")
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("2")
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("1")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ("GO")
  add1 = (randint(0,99))
  print ("What's", add1, "+", add2, "?")
  addansm = int(input("Write your answer here:"))
  addans = add1 + add2
  addans = int()
  if addans and addansm == addans :
    print ("Correct!")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    running2 = True
    running = False
  else : 
    print ("Try again!")
    running = False
```

Thank you for your help, Some extra information is that as soon as

```
print ("What's", add1, "+", add2, "?")
```

Happens I want the 5 second timer to start

Thanks you very much!